# SkyDrive backup questions

Tags: backup, cloud, synchronization, onedrive

I have set-up a SkyDrive account to use as an off-site backup so when I have finished a day's work I copy changed files (eg. from c:\myfiles) to my SkyDrive folder (mapped to S:), which then synchronises the files with the 'cloud' versions.  I never modify files directly in S:.

Questions:
1.  When a file is updated in the SkyDrive folder, does the synchronisation re-send the whole file, or only the changed parts of the file (ie. is it a full or incremental update?)
2.  When I see files in the SkyDrive folder as S:\ in Windows Explorer, are they duplicates of the original files (eg. copied from c:\myfiles) or just a reference to the original for syncing with the 'cloud' versions?

Any help would be appreciated.

Alan Harris-Reid

Comment: I note post has been marked-down as "does not show any research effort, it is unclear or not useful".  From my point-of-view it is a genuine question to which I would appreciate an answer from you folk out there who know about SkyDrive.  I did research the subject before posting, but cannot find the answers anywhere, hence the posting.

Disappointed to see 3 requests for closure so far - why?

Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possibly because of the files on drive S: are duplicates. At least that is my experience.

Comment: As I suspected :-( .  Thanks for the reply.